# MS Project AddIn which PDF-Printer to use for filename and start/end date?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, ms-project

I am developing an AddIn for MS Project 2013 and higher and I am looking for an PDF-Printer which i am able to give a filename and a range of dates.

With the Microsoft Print to PDF I am not able to give a start and end date.#

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861858/msproject-add-in-to-convert-mpp-in-pdf-with-given-name-and-date) I have tried several other solutions, but only using a pdf- printer gives me the overview I need. All other solutions are to much zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't find a nice solution in the last days I worked with the Windows to PDF printer on a Windows10 System and a third party printer on a Windows7 System.

I use the default FilePrint methode and insert the path via simulated keyboard input. I know this solution is not pretty and only works if the user does not interfere the programm, but it worked for me.